# haders JS file with dependable of the variables

Tags: javascript, karate

first Karate is the best tool for API automation. Period. :D

I have setup a file called headers.js. As one of the headers contains the "locale variable" like -> var headers = { 'X-Country-Code': "US" ...} I need that as a global variable to be able to set other variables based on its value, but as it is specifically into the headers function, how I access its value within a karate.feature file?

JS headers.js

```
function fn() {
  var env = 'us';

  if (!env) {
    env = 'us'; 
    }   
    var headers = { 'X-Country-Code': "us", 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };
  if (!env) {
    env = 'ca'; 
    }   
    var headers = { 'X-Country-Code': "ca", 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' };
    return headers;

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe all you need to do is set a global variable via `karate-config.js` and then use it everywhere else, including the headers JS function.

Anyway, you can set a variable from JS in extreme cases, this is kind of mentioned in the docs, but easy to miss: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure-headers

> In rare cases you may need to set a variable from this routine, and a good example is to make the generated UUID "visible" to the currently executing script or feature. You can easily do this via [`karate.set('someVarName', value)`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-set).

So this should work:

```
karate.set('currentCountryCode', headers['X-Country-Code']);
```

But this would be available within a feature file only *after* an HTTP request was made because the "headers function" is invoked just before the HTTP call. If you need it *before*, you have to figure out a different approach, and do note that `karate.get('someVariableName')` can do the reverse of `karate.set()`.

Also remember that if you want to get the headers after an HTTP request was made you can use [`karate.prevRequest.headers`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/request/request.feature).

Comment: Thank you Peter. You are of course right. My problem, putting it in headers.js, and not in the karate-config.js is that I had there karate.callSingle for a say "login.karate", and when I called it from other *.karate files, I didn't get the header values. I fixed it up, so no need for headers.js anymore. :)